# Zoom In/Out particular Object with Touch in Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I wanted to get Zoom In/Out functionality worked for the particular Object with Touch in Fabric JS.

I found that whole canvas being zoom in/out but for specific object from multiple is not possible.

Can anyone help how to achieve?

I tried to search multiple solutions online, but could not get answer for specific object zoom with touch

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Object zoom is really just scaling the object up, and touch really has little to do with it as you just need a way of interacting coupled with changes the scale of an object.

Comment: Here is the example, http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-5#pan_zoom

Reference to zoom in/out => it zoom all objects under canvas, I want to do only zoon the object which is selected from 2 finger touch.